I cannot convert my wav file to ima, why?
I'm trying to convert my wav file to an ima file but I don't know why it doesn't work. In fact when I tab the Enter key of my keyboard, nothing happens. Take a llok at the screenshot:

I expected to get an IMA file. Is there any problem?

did you check to see if there's a c:\bingo.ima file there?
